# Using Arrays from a different Class

Tags: java

```
public class NewClass { 
    int[] anArray = {1,2,3,4};
}

public class NewerClass {     
    public static void main(String[] args){
        sendToMethod(NewClass.anArray);
    } 
}
```

Obviously how i've written it above doesn't work, i was wondering how (if possible) it could be done?

Basically i want to have a class of arrays (`NewClass`) and want to be able to use them with the methods from the `NewerClass` whilst in the main method of `NewerClass`.

Its not essential, I'm simply playing around with ideas.

Comment: Also you can have a look 'java encapsulation' 'java access modifiers' keywords from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose it via an accessor method:

```
public class NewClass {
    private int[] anArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    public int[] getAnArray() {
        return anArray;
    }
}

public class NewerClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass myNewClass = new NewClass();
        sendToMethod(myNewClass.getAnArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst playing around, i used this: `sendToMethod(NewClass.class.newInstance().anArray);` and it seems to work?
Your code looks nicer though...

Comment: The way you did it there would be a bit roundabout, and isn't much different from `(new NewClass()).anArray`.

Comment: @qwertyRocker it's definitely better to do it the way @RobHruska describes, do not use `NewClass.class.newInstance()`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help :D I think i'm going to give them accessor methods, seems more sensible and easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

It would work if you had it like this:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static final int[] anArray = {1,2,3,4};
    // final is optional.
}
```

but I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either

```
public class   NewClass { static int[] anArray = {1,2,3,4}; }
```

or

```
public class NewerClass { 
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        sendToMethod(new NewClass().anArray); 
    }
}
```