# Accessing an array from a different object

Tags: java, arrays, object, compare

I have been doing an assessment for school. It is requiring me to make 2 arrays each within a different object. Nothing too fancy just getting some random numbers. Everything goes exactly the way I want but.. when I try to compare two arrays from both different objects it goes wrong. Here's my code

```
public class Opdracht8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Verzameling A = new Verzameling (20, 3);
    System.out.println("Verzameling A:\n" + A);
    System.out.println();

    Verzameling B = new Verzameling (20, 4);
    System.out.println("Verzameling B:\n" + B);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("A deelverzameling van B? " + A.deelverzamelingVan(B));

    }
}
```

and the "calculating part"

```
import java.util.Random;

class Verzameling {
   static int [] elementen;

    Verzameling(int aantal, int seed) {
        elementen = new int[aantal];
        Random randomGenerator = new Random(seed);
        int [] tijdelijkeArray = new int [100];
        /* Vullen van de vergelijkings array met de waarde van 1 tot 100 
         */

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter ++) {
            tijdelijkeArray[counter] = counter + 1;
        }

        /* Random getal genereerder. Hier vind het ook het swappen plaats dmv een 
         * temporary variable
         */

        for (int index = 0; index < aantal; index ++) {
            int randomNumber = index + randomGenerator.nextInt(100 - index);

            int temp = tijdelijkeArray[index];
            tijdelijkeArray[index] =  tijdelijkeArray[randomNumber];
            tijdelijkeArray[randomNumber] = temp;

        }   

        for(int index = 0; index < aantal; index++) {
            elementen[index] =  tijdelijkeArray[index];
        }
    } 

    Verzameling(int[] elementen) {
        this.elementen = elementen;

    }

    boolean deelverzamelingVan(Verzameling V) {

        for (int counter = 0; counter < this.elementen.length; counter ++) {
            if (this.elementen[counter] == V.elementen[counter]) {
                System.out.println(this.elementen[counter] +" " +  V.elementen[counter]);
                if (counter == (this.elementen.length - 1)) {
                    return true;
                }    
                continue;
            }
            else
                return false;

        }
        return false;


    }



    public String toString () {
        String reeks = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < elementen.length; i ++)
            reeks = reeks + elementen[i] + " ";

        return reeks;
    }   
}
```

I am sorry for the picking of odd variable names. But do you have any idea how to solve this. I have tried alot of things and getting pretty frustrated at the moment.

Comment: *"when I try to compare two arrays from both different objects it goes wrong"*: Please elaborate. **What** goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks Rohit for editting the post :)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627972/using-arrays-from-a-different-class/13628001#comment18691066_13628001

Comment: I am trying to compare the results of the array in object A and B. The only thing he's comparing is the array from Object B and B. He is not accepting the first array.

Comment: The thing is. I cant add any other methods into it. My school is really firm and wants it in this outline, draft. I have to stick with A.deelverzamelingVan(B).

Comment: Also, please explain exactly what you are trying to do and what the expected outcome is. Are you trying to determine if the two arrays contain the same elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arrays comparison you can use Java SE method `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)`.

Also you declared your `elementen` as **static**.

Comment: I did that all the way on top of the second script. It is a bit more complicated but I need to check wether the values of array 1 exists in array 2. So it doesnt has to be on the exact some position.

Comment: Damn... Thanks I see it! Ah finally. Thank you so much. I can finally proceed with my assignment

Comment: I accepted it but due to a lack of rep I can't upvoted it. Tried :(